# Coming soon: Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderation, election, moderators

We would like to give you a heads-up that in June, we will hold a moderator election to fill the slot for a third moderator to fill in for our long-time moderator [Dawny33](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/11097). **We will kick off the election on June 6th with question collection for the new candidates.** This gives you some time to think about if you want to nominate yourself or others and get even more involved in the community.

Looking forward to your contribution in the coming election process.